# If I can take two objects arbitrarily close to each other, does that mean they are the same?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

As the title says. If $\forall \epsilon\in \mathbb{R}>0$, there is $a,b \in K$ (an arbitrary set), such that $a-b<\epsilon$, does that imply $a = b$?
And what if $a-b<\frac{1}{n}$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}?$

Comment: Presumably you mean $|a-b|$ and also require $K\subseteq\Bbb R$?

Comment: I feel very uncomfortable that you said "object".  If you mean numbers than the answer is yes (more on that later).  But what if my set is {an equilateral triangle, the permutations of six elments, Sammy-- the blue elephant} what does equilateral triangle - sammy-- the blue elephant < $\epsilon$ mean?  You need.... to be continued....

Comment: You need some method of subtracting the elements.  You need so concept that if you subtract any two you always get a ***NON-zero*** real number.  You need the idea that if A - B = 0 then the elements are the same thing.  If you get that then:  A-B = K < e for all e > 0$ means that $0 \le K < e$ for all $e > 0$.  The *ONLY* such ***NUMBER*** is 0.  So A-B = 0.  So A is the same as B.

Comment: What you wrote is not what you meant to ask. In the first question, rather than being fixed, $a,b $ may vary wirh $\epsilon $. Most likely what you meant to ask was whether, for any $a,b\in\mathbb R $, if it is the case that $|a-b|<\epsilon $ for any $\epsilon>0$ , then $a=b $. Note the change in the order of quantifiers, and that a "there exists" should instead be a "for all". And note that there is no $K $. If the mention of $K $ was not a typo, you need to clarify what it is.

Comment: I assume you're working in a field with an absolute value with which you can define the distance.  The way you've stated it, $a$ and $b$ depend on $\epsilon$.  The right way is to say if $a$ and $b$ are fixed and $|a-b|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then does it follow that $a=b$?  The answer is yes.  Same thing is true if you just restrict $\epsilon$ to be of the form $1/n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the case when $a<b$. The "closeness" of $a,b\in{\bf R}$ should be measured by $|a-b|$, not $a-b$.

On the other hand, if one has
$$
|a-b|<\epsilon\quad \hbox{for all } \epsilon>0
\tag{*}
$$
then one has $a=b$, which can be easily proved by contradiction.

And yes, one can replace $\epsilon$ with $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\epsilon>0$ with $n\in{\bf N}$ in ($*$).

Comment: What's the mathematical justification?

Comment: Try to prove by contradiction.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Consider the Axiom of Archimedes. (Note: despite the name, this is a theorem, not an axiom.)

Answer (score 4):

I think too much symbolism tends to make even obvious things highly complicated and this question is a clear example of this phenomenon.

---

If we have two distinct real numbers (one may take any concrete examples like $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ to aid in thinking) then their difference is a fixed positive real number and these two numbers lie at that particular distance from each other. Thus they can't be more close to each other than that particular distance. It is thus clear that if two fixed numbers are arbitrarily close to each other then they can't be distinct.

---

Such obvious properties of real numbers (which hold for rationals too) are immediate consequences  of the way order relations are defined on real numbers and *unfortunately* most real-analysis textbooks are able to convert these things into *seemingly sophisticated stuff* by using Greek symbols like $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

What objects and how do you define closeness?  And what assumptions are you making about objects occupying the same space.

Take to two circles $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $(x - 2)^2 + y^2 + 1$.  They touch at $(1,0)$ so the are zero distance apart.  But the are not the same.

But...

If you have the premises that

i) for any two $a, b \in K$ there is some way of "measuring" $a$ from $b$ by $d(a,b)$ which we *could* notate as $a - b$.

Usually, we also specify that $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$ and we *don't* notate $a-b$ but $|a -b|$. (Usually, we want $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$ and we don't usually like $a-b = b-a$. However to prove, just your statement, we don't actually need those conditions.

ii)  $d(a,b) \ge 0$

This is another reason we don't usually use the notation $a-b$.  We need $a-b \ge 0$.

iii) If $d(a,b) = 0$ then it must be true that $a =b$.

Usually, we have this as an if and only if statement.  If $a = b$ then $d(a,b) = 0$.  This actually isn't required for your statement.

IF you have those premises, then your statement is true.  It is purely a matter about real number.

If $d(a,b) = L$ for some real number $L \ge 0$.  And if for ALL $\epsilon > 0$ then $L < \epsilon$, then there is only one such non-negative real number.  That is $0$.  So $L = 0$ and so $d(a,b) = 0$ so $a = b$.

To show that if a) $L \ge 0$ and b) $L < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ implies that $L = 0$.  Consider:

We know $L \ge 0$ so $L > 0$ or $L = 0$.  Suppose $L > 0$.  Then let $\epsilon = L$.  We have $L < \epsilon = L$.  This is impossible.  So $L \not > 0$.  So $L = 0$.

====

Such conditions are often called a metric.  A metric is a set of elements, $K$,  and a two variable function $d$ so that:

i) $d(a,b)$ is a real number for all $a,b \in K$ and $d(a,b) \ge 0$. And $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$.

ii) $d(a,b) = 0$ if and only if $a = b$.

iii) $d(a,c) \le d(a,b) + d(b,c)$ for all $a,b,c \in K$.

A classic example of a metric is $K = \mathbb R$ and $d(a,b) = |a-b|$.

Another is $K = \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ and $d((x_0, y_0),(x_1,y_1)) = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1- y_0)^2}$.

If $d$ is a metric and $d(a,b) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ then, yes,, $d(a,b) = 0$ and $a = b$.

=======

Addendum:  You aske what if $a-b < \frac 1n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Assuming you meant $|a - b| < \frac 1n$ then this is still true.

Supposet $|a - b| \ne 0$.  Then $|a -b| > 0$.  Let $M = \frac 1{|a-b|}> 0$.

Let $n > M$  Then $\frac 1n < \frac 1M = \frac 1{\frac 1{|a-b|}}= |a-b|$.

That is a contradiction.  So $|a-b| \not > 0$.  So $|a-b| = 0$  So $a-b = 0$ .  So $a =b$.

Answer (score 0):

I infer from your use of "objects" and from the tag "real analysis" that you are trying to think more generally than numbers on the real line using standard relational operators.  That is good, and in that case the answer is "not necessarily", but you need to think in different ways.  Start with the concept of *metric*. If you are studying Real Analysis, this is analogous to "measure".  In that case you will note that two sets can both be of measure zero and not be the same set.

A metric is a function, $\mu$ defined on ordered pairs of a set *S* such that $\mu: S \times S\rightarrow \Re[0,\infty) $, and such that the following properties all hold for $a,b,c \in S$. 
$$\mu(a,b) = 0 \iff a = b$$
$$\mu(a,b) = \mu(b,a)$$
$$\mu(a,c) \le \mu(a,b) + \mu(b,c) $$

On the Real line, $\eta(a,b)=|a-b|$ is the commonly-used metric, but the Delta Function: $$\delta(a,b) = \{^{0 \space (a=b)}_{1 \space otherwise} $$ is also a metric. Any *norm* on a vector space is a metric.  And so, we can define metrics for functions and all manner of objects.  Now, we have a way to talk about the "distance" between (say) polynomials.

Part of the definition of a metric, and one of its most useful properties, is that whenever the metric between to objects becomes zero,  they are identical.  So, if you are in a metric space, the answer to your question is, unequivocally, "yes".

However, the world is not limited to metrics. For example, measure is not a metric.  A pseudometric has a nearly identical definition, except that first condition is weakened to
$$\mu(a,a) = 0, $$ leaving open the possibility that $\mu(a,b)=0$ for some $a\neq b$.  In that case, the set $$Q_a=\{x\in S:\mu(a,x)=0\} $$ is an *equivalence class*.  Equivalence is a concept related to equality, but not the same thing. Equality is the intersection of all equivalence classes.

One can look up the italicized terms in Wikipedia if one wishes.  I hope that this response was on-point and helpful.